# Is there a way to discover WCF method signatures without generating the client code

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

if I had access into a WSDL(WCF based) and assuming that I don't have the source code of that service, isn't there some way to discover methods signatures (with parameters) other than generating the client class using "svcutil.exe"?

just like the asmx days that used to list all methods and when you click at one of them it displays a page that shows the parameters of the web service.

Comment: Just read the WSDL (and the accompanying XSD) - they contain **all** the information about your services.... (that's the same thing that `svcutil` or `Add Service Reference` will do)

Comment: I read the whole wsdl file, it doens't show anything about the parameters of my methods [OperationContracts]

Comment: @Baseel, check XSD file.

Comment: @VinayC where would I find the XSD?

Comment: @Bassel, if you are adding a service reference in VS, you will find XSD in the same folder as WSDL file. As such, if you open the WSDL file, you will find schema imports (`<xsd:import`) with urls that point to corresponding XSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found what I exactly needed, it was the WCF Test Client that comes with Visual Studio. it's a great way to discover any service methods and parameters

Answer (score 1):

WSDL (along with XSD) is the ultimate service documentation and can be consumed by code. So you can generate your help page based on the WSDL.

.NET Framework 4 has [built-in help page for WCF Web Http Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442.aspx) - it's disabled by default and you need to enable it. I don't believe similar facility exists for SOAP based WCF services.

For ASMX services, there is a built-in page that generates html help based on WSDL. So you can try something similar or by perhaps modifying that page (`DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx`) - see [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/webservicedoc.aspx) to know about how asmx service help is generated.

Comment: I didn't know this was called the "help page" thanks for that.

Comment: What's the alternative for the help page for WCF SOAP services

Comment: @Bassel, as said in the answer, I don't believe that an alternative exists. You have to build your own logic to build help page by inspecting WSDL.

Comment: I found it, it's the WCF Test Tool, it shows everything about the service in a very simple manner, this is the alternative for the old Help page.